# Create-React-App with Express server backend

Tags: express, create-react-app

If create-react-app boilerplate project has its own server. Why would there be a need to add a express backend server? What benefit does having two servers in development bring? Why could one not use the create-react-app server as one server to reduce complexity, since in production the create-react-app JS files get bundled? Having a hard time understanding SSR with create-react-app and express.

Currently I am only running create-react-app and having a hard time understanding the need to have express server. If the create-react-app has one for you.

Answer (score 0):

In production, create react app server does not even exist. Because the only thing create-react-app is really doing for us giving us things like the live reload and linting, some error checking and we do not need any of those behaviors in production. Before we deploy our application we are going to build our react project. When we build our react project, create-react-app is going to take all the different javascript files, css files, everything inside src, will going to run webpack and babel over those files and then save a final production build file into the build folder. Then whenever a user comes to our application running on heroku or any other platform that you deployed your app, we were only going to be running our express api and anytime someone comes to our app we will just automatically send them  our HTML file and newly built javascript file that was just placed into that public folder.

Create-react-app exists to give us a good development experience and helps us make good react apps. When we go out to heroku and serve everything up, we have node express api which will automatically serve all the public assets like the bundle.js or main.js, root html file and all the css.

express server is needed to communicate with database and do the backend works. do not confuse create-react-app with next.js